# Is it possible to change the main stat used by Wizards/Monks in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, monk, gestalt

I'm starting a [gestalt character](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/gestaltCharacters.htm) in Pathfinder, and **really** want to play a wizard as my main path. Thing is, I also really want to make it work with a monk, but the Intelligence focus vs. Wisdom focus is bothering me.

I've found that some classes (Sorcerer, Gunslinger, maybe also Oracle) have options allowing them to change their main stat.

Is there some option, somewhere, allowing the same for the Wizard, and/or the Monk? There are so many equipment/feats/class options that there *might* be something, but I can't just go through all the books to find it.

I'm not looking at gestalt advice, but specifically at how to change the stat of these classes.

Comment: Can you please note what sources are allowed in your game?  The 3.5 splatbooks have tons of options, but many GMs (myself included) don't allow them.

Comment: Good point. Only Pathfinder books, and if possible some of the "main" ones.

Comment: Is published 3pp allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the restriction of Pathfinder only, this is not possible, based on my research.  There is no feat, prestige class, race, or magic item that will make a wizard use Wisdom for their spells, or make a monk use Intelligence for their special abilities.  Depending on exactly what you're looking for, you might be able to use Magus instead of Monk. Magi/Wizards can use wizard spells with spell combat as long as the spell is on both spell lists, and there's a magus arcana that lets you . If you want to have more defensive abilities, use the [Skirnir](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/skirnir) archetype.  It focuses on shield use, and gets a bunch of defensive bonuses.  A Mithral light shield gives no ASF for wizards, and only costs 1153.

If what you really want is an unarmed melee combatant that is also a wizard, then it looks like there's no way around the MAD from being a Monk/Wizard.  Then again, if you mainly focus on wizard stuff, and don't try to go toe-to-toe with enemies too much, you might be able to ignore Str and Dex, and just have a high Int and Wis, which is more reasonable.

Comment: For the sorcerer the Empyreal variant of the Celestial bloodline (Ultimate Magic) allow you to use Wisdom instead of Charisma, and the Sage variant of the Arcane bloodline (UM too) does the same with Intelligence. As for Gunslinger, the Mysterious Stranger archetype (Ultimate Combat) allows you to use Charisma, and the Mechanist archetype (The Secrets of Tactical Archetypes) allows you to use Intelligence. I'll probably make a more general question to regroup these for all classes.

Comment: If you want an unarmed melee combatant that is also a wizard, then there are MANY ways around that. Mostly, they involve keeping any monk fluff that you might want, and cutting the actual monk class out of the mix. Literally any other class in the game is capable of doing monk's schtick better than the monk, especially the wizard.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how much D&D 3.5e material is allowed in Pathfinder, but Carmendine Monk (*Champions of Valor*) or Kung-Fu Genius (*Dragon* magazine vol. 319) would work for you.

Comment: What's CoV?  I'm embarrassed to admit I can't think of which book that is off the top of my head.

Comment: Champions of Valor, one of the Forgotten Realms books.